# Saving data with sharedpreferences

Tags: android

Does SharedPreference work for when the user presses the back button.Then what is the way to store data when the user presses the back button.

Answer (score 1):

You can override the back button press and then work with the SharedPreferences:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)  {
    SharedPreferences SP =  = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
    SP.edit().putString(key, value);
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override the back button, and then store the value using shared preferences, if that's what you meant!

Comment: back button in the mobile i.e the application is killed

Answer (score 0):

Use onBackPressed method of Activity for this purpose:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    //Do stuff
    return;
}
```